# Showing that a function is concave

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Fix a fixed $0<\lambda<0.5$, consider the function
\begin{align}
f(p) 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1  -\lambda  + \lambda (1+p)^2}{(1 + \lambda( 1+2p))^2} + \frac{1 -\lambda + 4\lambda (1+p)^2}{(1 + \lambda( 1+2p))^2}-1}}.
\end{align}
How can I show that $f$ is concave in $p$ in an interval around zero?

I have checked numerically that this is true, and if it helps, we can consider the interval $-0.25<p<0.25$.

By looking at this function, can someone identify a procedure to show concavity, i.e., the steps required? I feel like brute-force differentiation is not the way to go, and it quickly becomes ugly.

Comment: The function simplifies to $f(p) = (\lambda p + \lambda  + 1) / \sqrt{(5\lambda -\lambda ^2)p^2 + (8\lambda -2\lambda ^2)p - \lambda ^2 + \lambda  + 1}$. I am afraid there is no easy way to show concavity.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are correct and resorted to the bulldozer method over the weekend.